# How to "connect" dynamically created UI switches?

Tags: node-red

I've used this flow https://gist.github.com/DeanCording/1541bcbba48bb088ec1503dba109f63c to dynamically create a set of md-switches on my UI corresponding to my sonoff devices.

How do I "connect" these dynamically created UI elements such that they reflect the current state and cause an action when clicked. I understand how to do these things if the UI switches were individually, manually defined in a flow, but I can't see how to incorporate a dynamic switch into a sequence.

NB. My question is specifically about **dynamically** created UI switches, ie. created with `template` and which do not appear in any of my flows.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you don't, at least not with what that gist is producing.

That script is using a template node to create Angular buttons that will open a new tab directly from the device (which I assume is also hosting it's own http interface as well as publishing/changing state via MQTT).

If you want to use the Node-RED Dashboard buttons to control your devices via MQTT then you will most likely have to wire them by hand.